# Reconstructing a functional from its Euler-Lagrange equations

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, inverse-problems

Is it true that Euler-Lagrange equations associated to a functional determine the functional?

Suppose I give you an equation and I claim that it is an Euler-Lagrange equation of some functional. Can you tell me what was the functional?

Of course, there is always more than one functional whith prescribed E-L equations, since the critical points of $E$ and of $\phi(E)$ where  $\phi:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and stirclty monotonic are identical.
(By the chain rule $ (\phi \circ f)'(x)=\phi'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$).

Is it true that there is a functional $E$ whose E-L equations are the 
prescribed ones, and every other functional with the same E-L equations is a function of $E$?

One can think on different ways to formalize this question like different choices for the domain of the functional: paths in a manifold, real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, mappings between Riemannian manifolds etc, but at this stage of the game I don't want to choose a specific form yet. (Although I am particularly interested in the latter case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It is well-known that

   - adding boundary/total divergence terms and/or
   - overall scaling

   of a functional preserve the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation).
2. On the other hand, there is in general no classification of possible functionals that lead to a given set of EL equations.
3. An instructive example from Newtonian point mechanics is given in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17406/2451) Phys.SE post, where two Lagrangians $L=T-V$ and $L=\frac{1}{3}T^2+2TV-V^2$ both have Newton's second law as their EL equation.
4. Another example: The functional in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2135074/11127) Math.SE post has the same EL equation as the functional $F[y]=\int_0^3  \! \mathrm{d}x~y^{\prime 2}.$